# Is OmniFaces cache component good for resource caching?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, servlet-filters, omnifaces

The question below,

> Primefaces, JQuery script and CSS files loading for each and every page refresh and ajax page update. How to get files from cache instead of downloading for each request.

was asked at the following:

[Primefaces script and css file loading for each page refresh](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=25797)

I recommended OmniFaces o:cache component. Can o:cache be used in this case, or is it still best to use servlet filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [OmniFaces `<o:cache>` showcase page](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/cache),

> The  component allows to cache a fragment of rendered markup.

So, I assume the answer to this question is 'no'.

Comment: That's correct. The `<o:cache>` serves an entirely different purpose.